# CreateRemoteThread Crashes Process

Tags: python, multithreading, ctypes

I am using the following script to inject Python 2.7 and find a function in the memory of the process it's injected in.

```
import os
import ctypes
from ctypes import *
from ctypes import wintypes

def InjectDLL(pid, filename, procname):
    PAGE_READWRITE = 0x04 #Set token values
    PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS = ( 0x00F0000 | 0x00100000 | 0xFFF )
    VIRTUAL_MEM = ( 0x1000 | 0x2000 )
    dll_len = len(filename)
    h_process = kernel32.OpenProcess( PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, False, int(pid) )
    arg_address = kernel32.VirtualAllocEx(h_process, 0, dll_len, VIRTUAL_MEM, PAGE_READWRITE)
    written = c_int(0)
    kernel32.WriteProcessMemory(h_process, arg_address, filename, dll_len, byref(written))
    h_kernel32 = kernel32.GetModuleHandleA("kernel32.dll")
    h_loadlib = kernel32.GetProcAddress(h_kernel32, "LoadLibraryA")
    thread_id = c_ulong(0)
    kernel32.CreateRemoteThread(h_process, None, 0, h_loadlib, arg_address, 0, byref(thread_id))
    address = GetRemoteProcAddress(pid, filename, procname)
    kernel32.CreateRemoteThread(h_process, None, 256, address, 0, 0, byref(thread_id))

def GetRemoteModuleHandle(pid, modname):
    modname = modname.upper()
    if '.' not in modname:
        modname += '.DLL'
    while True:
        try:
            hProcessSnap = kernel32.CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(
                                TH32CS_SNAPMODULE, pid)
            break
        except OSError as e:
            if e.winerror != ERROR_BAD_LENGTH:
                raise
    try:
        modentry = MODULEENTRY32W()
        kernel32.Module32FirstW(hProcessSnap,
                                ctypes.byref(modentry))
        while True:
            if modentry.szModule.upper() == modname:
                return modentry.hModule
            try:
                kernel32.Module32NextW(hProcessSnap,
                                       ctypes.byref(modentry))
            except OSError as e:
                if e.winerror == ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES:
                    break
                raise
        raise ctypes.WinError(ERROR_MOD_NOT_FOUND)
    finally:
        kernel32.CloseHandle(hProcessSnap)

def GetRemoteProcAddress(pid, filename, procname):
    procname = procname.encode('utf-8')
    global hLocal
    hLocal = kernel32.LoadLibraryExW(filename, None,
                                     DONT_RESOLVE_DLL_REFERENCES)
    try:
        procaddr = kernel32.GetProcAddress(hLocal, procname)
    finally:
        kernel32.FreeLibrary(hLocal)
    modname = os.path.basename(filename)
    hRemote = GetRemoteModuleHandle(pid, modname)
    return hRemote - hLocal + procaddr


InjectDLL(13052, 'python27.dll', 'Py_InitializeEx')
```

This isn't the *full* script, that would be too long. Everything that is needed is here, the rest are error handlers and ctype structures.

My problem is that, even though it finds the address perfectly (I have verified with a process memory editor) it cannot execute the remote thread on that address or else the process will close immediately and crash.

The injection works fine, it's just the execution of said function that crashes it. Can anybody see a problem in my script? Thanks.

NOTE: I have verified that both the python dll and the running executable are BOTH 32 bit.

The ENTIRE problem lies within this line of code:

```
kernel32.CreateRemoteThread(h_process, None, 256, address, 0, 0, byref(thread_id))
```

If this is commented out, the script runs fine (even though the function isn't run). However, when run, this causes the crash.